# I cant verify seed generation if someone can see what is wrong

Tags: python, algorithm, random, bitwise-operators

So i got this function that generates seeds **makeseed()** and now im trying to make a "verify" seed keep in mind that any seed generated IS **Correct** so i want it so that the user can input seeds and it'll check if its valid or not.

here is my code

```
import random

def getchecksum(seed):
    checksum = 0
    while True:
        checksum = (checksum + (seed & 0xFF)) & 0xFF
        checksum = (2 * checksum + (checksum >> 7)) & 0xFF
        seed >>= 5
        if seed == 0:
            break
    return checksum

def makeseed():
    seed = random.randint(1, 4294967295)
    checksum = getchecksum(seed)
    abc = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZ01234V6789"
    seedsprev = ((seed ^ 0xFEF7FFD) << 8) | checksum
    finalseed = ""
    for loopindex in range(0, 8):
        finalseed = abc[seedsprev & 0x1F] + finalseed
        seedsprev >>= 5
    return finalseed

def is_valid_seed(seed):
    """
    Checks if a seed is valid.

    Args:
        seed: The seed to check.

    Returns:
        True if the seed is valid, False otherwise.
    """
    seed_length = len(seed)
    if seed_length != 8:
        return False

    abc = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZ01234V6789"

    try:
        seed_int = 0
        for i in range(7, -1, -1):
            seed_int <<= 5
            seed_int |= abc.index(seed[i])

        checksum = getchecksum(seed_int)
        seed_int = ((seed_int ^ 0xFEF7FFD) << 8) | checksum

        final_seed = ""
        for _ in range(8):
            final_seed = abc[seed_int & 0x1F] + final_seed
            seed_int >>= 5

        return final_seed == seed
    except ValueError:
        return False

ok = makeseed()
print(is_valid_seed(ok)) #to check if the function is correct
print(ok)
```

I tried to reverse what the **makeseed** did and i was expecting it to work but it didnt

Comment: What does it mean for a seed to be "valid"?

Comment: Are you trying to do https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b32encode ?

Comment: Are you sure the algorithm in `makeseed()` is reversible?

Comment: @Barmar I have come here to see if someone would be able to help reversing it i do not know if it is reversable.

Comment: @KennyOstrom i am using that but this is mainly for my project.

Comment: I have a feeling that it isn't reversible, due to the way it mixes up the bits with XOR and shift.

Comment: checksum is different in your reversed calculation. I'll see if it can verify using the original checksum when I get a moment, but I assume Barmar's right.

Comment: @KennyOstrom i have been thinking about this but basically what i could do is calculate the sum of the seed and see if it between 1 and 4294967295  since all seeds will be between those 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string encode/decode was bad because you reassembled the digits in reverse order. The best way to test for something like that is to split out the encode and decode to separate functions so you can run a unit test like decode(encode(x)) == x. I probably would have used an existing library like base32, base64 or just hexadecimal.

Your reversal of the checksum operations also didn't actually reverse the operations. It just did some of the same math in the same order, not the reverse order.

The thing you need to check in is_valid_seed is whether the checksum actually checks out.

```
MY_ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZ01234V6789"

def encode(seed: int) -> str:
    encoded = ""
    for _ in range(0, 8):
        value = seed & 0x1F
        seed >>= 5
        encoded = MY_ALPHABET[value] + encoded
    return encoded


def decode(encoded: bytes) -> int:
    seed = 0
    for digit in encoded:
        value = MY_ALPHABET.index(digit)
        seed <<= 5
        seed += value
    return seed


assert(99999 == decode(encode(99999)))


def getchecksum(seed: int):
    checksum = 0
    while True:
        checksum = (checksum + (seed & 0xFF)) & 0xFF
        checksum = (2 * checksum + (checksum >> 7)) & 0xFF
        seed >>= 5
        if seed == 0:
            break
    return checksum


def make_seed(seed: int):
    checksum = getchecksum(seed)
    seedsprev = ((seed ^ 0xFEF7FFD) << 8) | checksum
    return encode(seedsprev)


def is_valid_seed(encoded: str):
    seed = decode(encoded)
    checksum = seed & 0xff
    original_seed = (seed >> 8) ^ 0xFEF7FFD
    return checksum == getchecksum(original_seed)


assert is_valid_seed(make_seed(7777))
assert not is_valid_seed('ABCDEFGH')
```

Comment: by the way in the line:  assert is_valid_seed(make_seed(7777)
you forgot a ')' and thank you.

Comment: The actual base32 digits were all correct, so the bitwise operations look the same, but they were reassembled in reverse order. It's like saying 35,622 == 22, 653 in base 10. The digits were the same, but the numbers are not. A test like assert decode(encode(x)) == x verifies the problem in the original code, and the fix here. Edited.